# UV unwrapping wrong placed parts

Tags: uv

I made this santa doll in seperate parts, cause i figured this would be easier with the shape of it. But now all the parts are obviousy loose even though together in 1 mesh group. So when i unwrap them they come out as loose part in the uv, but i prefer them to be the exact shape of the doll, so the texturing would be easy. How do i get this done? All the loose parts are also wrongly places and turned as you can see... This is useless for texturing and will take me a day to figure out.[image]

Comment: *"This is useless for texturing"* only if you're trying to export this UV layout into 2D image and color it in 2d image editor. Other than that there's texture painting in Blender where you can edit currently visible in viewport texture in 2d editor as well. If going with 1 piece then connect all meshes into one

Answer (score 1):

Simple, use **[Project From View](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/uv_image/uv/editing/unwrapping/mapping_types.html#project-from-view)** when **Unwrapping**.

[image: final]